# using ip command to display a specific IP address among many

Tags: linux, rhel

On a Red Hat 6 server (I don't need to be told this is deprecated) I have multiple interfaces and multiple IP addresses. However, only one of these addresses has the Secondary flag. I'm trying to find a command to just show this IP and nothing else, so it can be put in a variable in a script.

The best I've been able to come up with so far (without grepping/awking it to death anyway) is `ip a show secondary` which does show only the secondary IP, but it also shows extranuous information like the MAC for every interface, all the interface names, etc.

I got that far with the `ip` man page, but I can't see a way to show only the secondary-labeled IP address *without* all the other stuff. Is it possible without using something like `awk` to parse it out?

Comment: Welcome to the site. If you could edit your post to show a (possibly anonymized) example of the `ip a show secondary` command, contributors are likely able to help you.

Comment: Newer iproute2 tools have a JSON output to be easily used with the jq command. I doubt it's available in RHEL6.